# Write Multiple Lines in Tkinter Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter entry of a big size (I want to write multiple paragraphs inside it). I tried to achieve that by increasing ipady and ipadx (`entry.grid(row =0, column = 0, ipadx = 50, ipady = 50)`)and it resulted in a bigger entry, but the text still gets written in only one line and doesn't fill the whole entry. What do you suggest doing?
[Here's a screenshot of the entry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZfmj.png)

Comment: Have a look at [the tkinter text widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112033110/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: entries are specifically designed to only support a single line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Text widget

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('400x200')
t = tk.Text(window, width=100, height=100)
  
t.grid(column=1, row=15)
  
window.mainloop()
```

[image]